# Initializing datatable after the data is loaded into table

Tags: datatables

I am using datatable plugin
I have partial views and data is loaded into table by controller.

```html
<script type="text/template" id="dealer-row-template">
    <td>
        <p><a class="dealer-record" href="#"><%- dealerId %></a></p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p><%- dealerName %></p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p><%- dealerType %></p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p><%- phone %></p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p><%- city %></p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p><%- state %></p>`enter code here`
    </td>
    <td>
        <p><%- country %></p>
    </td>
</script>
```

I have tried all the methods in the website and other solutions. I am not able to initialize datatable on table load. Please provide me with a solution.

Comment: Seems you want to use a html5 template for rows. Please show the relevant code, there is no datatable initialization above.

Comment: an example of initialization is `$('table').DataTable();`